# Should I programly put computation-heavy tasks on a separate thread on IOS to utilize multi-core?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making a real-time image processing app on IOS with my team. I am handling the custom computation kernel (mostly on CPU rather than GPU) and my teammates deals with the GUI. When I tested my kernel on a toy app, the core (ignoring any IO overhead ) runs steadily at 100ms per image. However, when put into the full-functioning one, it is slowed down to 500ms per image.

I have checked that the data is pretty much the same and I am only measuring time consumed within the kernel, on the same iphone6. There are hardly any other computation in the full-functioning app so I am not sure what is pulling behind. Though GPU-processing is definitely an alternative and I am working on it, I would like to know if there is any tricks to use for now.

Currently, there is no explicit multi-threading in the computation part, so my simple guess is: should I programly put the computation part on a separate thread so the second core can be utilized?

[Update]

It turns out that I made some mistakes in packing my code as library, as the copying over the source code works out nicely. I have not figured out my problem yet and am going to post it on a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890858/significantly-slower-computation-using-library-as-compared-to-source-code-on-ios).

Comment: If you don't know what's eating CPU then you need to use *Instruments* to find out.  Only then can you start to think about solving any performance issues.

Comment: There's no way a sane UI layer can eat 80% CPU. So it must be something else that brings your 100ms to 500 when embedding into the main app. It can be too frequent UI updates, some kind of resource contention or just a bug in how to use the kernel. As @trojanfoe says: you have to measure what's going on and why it's different from the test app.

Comment: Thanks forks! I am going to dig it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GPU Acceleration

This massively depends on the tasks you're performing, the GPU is good a specific subset of tasks and simply utilising it can sometimes even slow things down. [Check this out](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/01/05/exploring_gpgpu_on_ios/)

A lot of image based tasks that are part of the `Quartz` framework e.t.c are GPU accelerated (like blurring). Also if you use a library like `OpenCV` you get GPU acceleration on certain tasks out the box.

Unless you're a real pro I would avoid using the GPU specifically and let the frameworks and libraries you use do that for you.

> Concurrency

It will certainly help to put intensive tasks on a background thread. Just be aware of what it entails (i.e. you can't make any `UIKit` calls from a background thread.

Comment: Understood. I have too many proprietary algorithm to make use of the off-the-shelf packages,  and my GPU development has been rewarding so far.  Anyway, thanks! I am going to read more on concurrency and see how much it helps.

Comment: Out of interest what are you using for your GPU development? And have you tried [`OpenCV`](http://opencv.org)?

Comment: It is a modified SURF algorithm. I tried openCV on PC (on CPU) and it is significantly slower than my code for my specific application. Besides, I don't think openCV can utilize openGLES on IOS yet, without which none-image computation can hardly be GPU-accelerated.

Comment: Interesting stuff! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The answer heavily depends on how you do the processing. Some methods in the SDK perform their job in a background thread, while others require the caller to create and use one.

In general, in the case of drawing, most methods require you to create one explicitly. This is important especially for the ones that perform their work on the CPU (e.g. using CoreGraphics to draw within a drawRect method). If you're using methods that use GPU for the processing, then creating threads won't be much of use since CPU won't be the cause of the bottleneck.

If you want to determine why your app slows down, use Instruments. (Time Profiler for CPU and Core Animation for drawing)

Comment: Thanks for the input!